# Como colocar prefixo de moeda (R$) na barra de status do pacote shinyWidgets do R?

Tags: r, shiny

Existe alguma forma de mostrar os números como moeda (R$), incluindo separador de milhares e centavos, nas barras de progresso do pacote shinyWidgets do shiny? 
Estou tentando rodar alguns códigos, mas todos eles convertem números para strings, então o shiny não consegue calcular.

No exemplo, eu gostaria que ficasse assim:

R$1.000.000,70/R$5.000.000,29

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
        progressBar(id = "pb1", value = 1000000.70, 
                    total = 5000000.29, status = "info", display_pct = TRUE, striped = TRUE, 
                    title = "DONATION"),

        progressBar(id = "pb2", value = as.numeric(1000000.70, options(scipen=999)), 
                    total = as.numeric(5000000.29, options(scipen=999), status = "info", display_pct = TRUE, striped = TRUE, 
                    title = "DONATION")
)
)
server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Não costumo utilizar o Shiny, mas um ```paste0``` junto com a função ```format``` antes dos valores não resolveria?

Comment: Olá! A função paste (e paste0) convertem entradas numéricas em string. Em sendo assim o shiny não consegue fazer o calculo da proporçao entre o valor total e a entrada e dá erro. Obrigado pela contribuição, Alexandre.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função `dollar_format` do pacote `scales`, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
library(scales)

real <- dollar_format(prefix = "R$ ")
```

Basta utilizar a função com qualquer valor dentro que retornará com o prefixo "R$". Ex.:

```
real(10)

#> [1] "R$ 10"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por estar junto comigo tentando decifrar esse dilema. rs

Comment: Espero ter ajudado, se considerou útil essa resposta, por favor, marque como "resposta aceita" clicando no check. Obrigado!

Comment: Continuamos na mesma situação. Passando o valor pelo "dollar_format", ele continua tranformando o objeto de formato numeric para string. Dessa maneira o shiny não consegue calcular. Muito obrigado por estar junto comigo tentando decifrar esse dilema. rs